# Linux Command to find out "count" of running process?

Tags: linux

There are 3 processes. I have to find the "count" of running process in current directory.

```
# named ../sample
```

And:

```
[root@sp3 sample]# ps -eaf|grep perl
root     14104     1 58 08:39 ?        03:31:34 perl example1.pl
root     17441     1 41 09:09 ?        02:17:24 perl example2.pl
root     24543     1  0 Jul05 ?        00:00:00 perl sample.pl
[root@sp3 sample]#
```

The result I have to return is 3.

I have currently in sample directory and I have to count the number of process in same directory

Please post any solution.

Comment: `ps aux | grep  perl | grep -vc grep`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
LOCAL_PWD = pwd
ps -auxeaf| grep $LOCAL_PWD| wc -l
```

wc -l counts lines

Regarding how to show full path of processes please take a look at [here](https://superuser.com/questions/103309/how-can-i-know-the-absolute-path-of-a-running-process)

Comment: This results all the process running in all directories but i have to count all the process running in current directory.

Comment: then add a grep for current dir in between the command's pipeline and use ps switch to show full path of processes

Comment: I have tried this


ps -eaf|grep perl| grep /var/www/anand/sample| wc -l

but it returns count 0 please post any solution

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't the right place for this (there's a linux part of stackexchange). But you can use `wc` to count lines in any output, so pipe your command to it like this: `ps -eaf | grep perl | wc -l`. By the way I'd also recommend making the `grep` command not match itself by doing `grep [p]erl` (putting []'s around any one character will still match only 'perl', but the grep command no longer has 'perl' in it).

In case it's of use to you I've put together a script like I mentioned in the comment below.

```
total=0
for file in $(find -executable -type f) ; do
    echo "Checking $file:"
    count=$(ps -ef | awk '{print $8}' | grep "^.*/*${file##*/}$" | wc -l)
    echo "$count processes found."
    total=$(($total + $count))
done
echo $total
```

Comment: This results all the process running in all directory i have to count 
all the process running in current directory.

Comment: It sounded from what you said as though you had the list of items already and just wanted them counted. I see you've clarified now, unfortunately it's a lot harder to do that specifically as ps doesn't necessarily provide that information (to my knowledge). Would it be satisfactory to have a small script that checks for all executables in the current directory and looks for those by name in the ps output? The disadvantage with that of course is that if you have an executable with the same name elsewhere you can't easily differentiate them.

Comment: That looks like the most complex solution provided to this really trivial problem

Comment: @fork0 It's no longer a trivial problem when you require only showing running processes from executables in the current directory.

Comment: Well, than at least use `awk` instead of `grep`, move `wc` out of the loop and remove the counting with a variable, `wc` will do that for you

Comment: And BTW, it has quadratic complexity. You better don't try the code on a busy system in /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
ps -eaf | grep perl | grep -v grep | wc -l

Comment: typo - should be perl. fixed

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is old, but there is no solution for this Problem.

---

***Solution 1***

`ps ax |egrep "^/your/path/to/Script" |wc -l`

- ps ax = Processlist
- egrep = gets all processes from the list that
  start with the specified path. You need to start your Perl scripts
  with Path/Script.pl and not like ./script.
  ^ = Multiline - You can also use normal **grep "/your/path/to/script"**
- wc -l = Count all results
- Output = 3

---

***Solution 2***

Name you scripts with a specific identifier and grep for it like:

script_example_**ident**.pl

`ps ax |grep "ident" |wc -l`

Answer (score -1):

If by running you mean "queued for execution":

```
ps ax -o stat,args |grep '^R'|wc -l
```

Comment: I have to count all the process running in current directory.

Comment: that's a bit harder for a simple shell magic. Take a look at lsof: the proccess with a working directory must reference it. So you can list all the processes which referenced the given directory, than find out which of these are actually queued for execution. To get the list of processes: `lsof .` (for current directory)

Comment: I have tried this


ps -eaf|grep perl| grep /var/www/anand/sample| wc -l

but it returns count 0 please post any solution

Comment: `lsof -t . |xargs ps -o stat,args |grep ^R |wc -l`

Comment: Or, if you don't need the running, just lingering in that dir, drop the `grep`

Comment: `lsof -t . |xargs ps -o stat,args |grep ^R |wc -l` this results 1 if you are in current directory but i have to get the count value as 3.

Comment: That's the part about "lingering in that dir". To get the count value you want, remove "|grep ^R". It restricts the process list to really *running*

Comment: Using `lsof` for this purpose is very brittle. You could very easily get false positives from for example a text editor having one of the scripts open.

Comment: @Thor84no: True. A more complete solution would be to filter only the lines with FD = cwd. It's ugly, though: `lsof -F pf |while read s;do test "$s" = fcwd && echo "${o:1}";o="$s";done`

Comment: Err... Not that ugly, after all: `lsof -F pf |grep fcwd|wc -l`

Comment: @fork0 That's an improvement. It however also assumes that the executable was started with that directory as a working directory (not the case if started from elsewhere using a full or relative path). I'm not sure there are any complete solutions to this problem, only ones with drawbacks you can live with.

Comment: @Thor84no: yes, I think there (completeness) we agree.